Proof of leaving Canada
My mother has a Canadian visit visa. She arrived in Canada in April 2024, but we are unsure how long she is allowed to stay, as her passport doesn't have any entry stamps from Canadian authorities.
I assume she needs to leave the country within 6 months.
In Mid August She traveled to the USA by car  (she also has a US visit visa) , and got her passport stamped by USA.
She came back to Canada through Canadian land borders on the next day
In early September, my mother and I traveled to the USA again by car through a land border crossing. There was no passport check when leaving Canada for the USA, so there's no record of her departure before the end of her 6-month stay.
How can we inform Canadian authorities that she left the country, and how can we confirm how long she is permitted to stay in Canada?
Here is the map of her trip

1 Apr 2024 : Jordan   ---[Airport]--->   Canada
6 Aug 2024:  Canada
---[Land]--->   USA {USA Stamped her passport}
7 Aug 2024:  USA      ---[Land]--->   Canada {No stamps}
9 Sep 2024:  Canada   ---[Land]--->   USA {No stamps}


The answer to the question asked in the title is: the US entry stamp in your mother's passport. The answer to the question asked in the question text — how to let Canada Immigration know she left on time — I don't know. Perhaps another user here will chime in with a response.

For the US a visit to bordering countries doesn't count toward resetting the allowed duration of stay. If Canada does the same (which I don't know) the trips to US do not count.

Looks like your mother has already spent nearly 6 months in Canada, with what looks like two brief visa runs to the US. If she wants to stay longer than 6 months from her first entry, she may be able to apply for a Visitor Record

Did the Canadian border officer who admitted her on August 7th say anything?

@phoog no, they did not say anything, they just let us entre the country without any question or comment

There is no need to inform the Canadian government that a temporary resident (or anyone else) has left Canada, unless the person is explicitly requested to do so due to a removal order ("deportation" in common speech, though the term has particular meaning in Canadian law).
Neither Canada nor US routinely stamp all travellers' passports anymore nor do they rely only on stamps for immigration enforcement purposes. The entry information are electronically recorded and you are supposed to know when you entered to calculate the authorized period (but yes, a website like the one to check I-94 in the US would be helpful).
Canada collects exit information by requiring air carriers to transmit passenger manifests and by data-sharing agreement with the United States. Entries to the United States from the land border with Canada is electronically shared with Canada and vice versa.
The default authorized period of stay in Canada is six months (exceptions below) at each entry, unless instructed otherwise by a border officer through a stamp annotation or visitor record (the explicit annotations or visitor records always prevail).
Complying with the authorized period of stay does not necessarily mean that future entries to Canada is not impacted. Extended stay and apparent "visa runs" may cause doubts as to the genuineness of the purpose of visit and the means of financial support.
If your mother's visa is a PG-1 supervisa issued to parents and grandparents of Canadian citizens or permanent residents, she can stay five years at each entry. The visa is designed for long-term stay and visa runs are usually not a concern, although the parent or grandparent visitor is still required to demonstrate through ties in the home country and financial resources that they will/are able to leave Canada at the end of authorized stay (that may be extended).
If your mother's visa is single-entry (which is rare), then the authorized period of stay starts from the first entry into Canada. Single-entry visas allow holders to return to Canada from a visit solely to the US within the original authorized period; in this case reentry from the US does not "reset" the authorized period of stay.
